# How can I do a Google search about GitHub without getting results from public repositories?

Tags: google-search, github

I tried to search a private code base on GitHub for a string that included a `[`<sup>*</sup>. It gave me a pretty 500 error page so I jumped over to Google and searched for "[github search special characters](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20search%20special%20characters)". Almost all of the results came back as links to issues from public repositories relating to special characters breaking search in their code.

How can I exclude results from public GitHub repositories?

I thought about restricting the search to `help.github.com` but that would exclude any results external to GitHub such as blog posts.

<sup>* I can search issues with strings that include square brackets, but not code.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough info to tell you what search operators to  use, but here are all of Google's advanced search operators:

http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html

You can string them together to get extremely specific results.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Github direct:

The best way is to use the "user:".  This is also exposed in the advanced interface.  See: https://github.com/search/advanced